# Latex and NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, latex, netbeans-plugins

I have NetBeans 8.0.2 EE edition. I'm wondering if there is a latex plugin supported by Netbeans in the same way as Texlipse plugin in Eclipse. I've been searching online about that but unfortunately I couldn't find a good plugin.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for it

I found this

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/5749/tex-language-support

you have to build de module, I did with the current code, but doesn't work, I will try to see what happened, you can try to do the same

good look

Answer (score 0):

The best plugin I know of is https://kenai.com/projects/nblatex/downloads .
I have used it extensively in the past, however, I have not tried to use it with a version of NetBeans higher than 7 and so I can't say if it works with the latest NetBeans.